# Magento 2: How to send id with the url in MVC pattern

Tags: magento2, url, controllers

I want to send the id with the URL for eg: `http://192.168.1.108/magento2/profile/id/34` and get `id` from the my controller.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To create URL with parameters use the below function:

**In Block class:**

```
$url = $this->getUrl('module_frontName/controller_name/action_name', array('id' => 450));
```

**In Controller class:**

```
$url = $this->_url->getUrl('module_frontName/controller_name/action_name', array('id' => 450));
```

**In Helper class:**

```
$url = $this->_getUrl('module_frontName/controller_name/action_name', array('id' => 450));
```

To get parameter value from the URL:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('parameter_name') // To get Single Param
$this->getRequest()->getParams() // To get array of all parameters
```

Comment: it take me to 404 page not found

Comment: http://localhost/magento/useraccount/profile/index/id/450/

Answer (score 0):

Send this url `http://host/controller/action?id=34`

And use below code in your controller to get **id**

```
echo $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Comment: no i dont want to send the query string parameters

Comment: the url should be `localhost/magento/profile/id/1/`